# What is the relation between $L^p([0,1])$ and the weak topology?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

In my course of functional analysis, we always work with a Hausdorff locally convex space when we're creating the weak* and weak topology. My professor once stated that there is a reason for this assumption and gave the example of $L^p([0,1])$ for $0<p<1$ (let me write $L^p$ for brevity). He showed that $(L^p)'=0$, but I didn't fully get the point of why he did this.

What is the relation between this fact and the weak topology on $L^p$? It seems that I'm missing something rather easy.

Comment: For locally convex spaces (aren't they always assumed to be Hausdorff?) we have the Hahn-Banach-Theorem which ensures that there are sufficient continuous linear functionals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that $L^p$, for $p \in (0,1)$ is *not locally convex*.

Your professor showed that its dual is zero, hence it wouldn't make sense to talk about weak topology as it is defined using elements in the dual space.

---

An easy way to convince yourself such spaces are not locally convex is to define the $L^p$ norm in $\mathbb R^2$ and draw the unit ball, for $p<1$, $p=1$ and $p>1$. You will see that for $p<1$ the unit ball is not a convex set.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. We haven't covered weak convergence yet, but we did talk a bit about weak continuity. Is there a link with the example of the zero dual space as well?

Comment: You mentioned weak topology in the question. Theorem 2.21 of [these notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/lpspace.pdf) is a proof that the dual of $L^p$ for $p \in (0,1)$ is $0$.

Comment: Nice PDF! We proved it in exactly the same way. I'm still not sure whether I understand you. For me, the weak topology on $E$ is the topology generated by the semi-norms $p_f: E\to \mathbb{R}: x\mapsto \lvert f(x)\rvert, f\in E'$.

Comment: Perfect: you say $f \in E'$, but in this case $E'=0$, so there are no $f$'s to generate the topology! So you can't define the weak topology! Tell me if I can make it clearer.

Comment: O, but of course! That was stupid of me. Thanks a lot for your very fast help! I'll give you an extra upvote.